# WPF - Esconder Componentes no Design

Tags: wpf

Boas pessoal,

Troquei recentemente de PC e no outro PC o visual studio 2010 no Design do WPF quando adicionava determinado objecto e definia a propriedade "visibility=Hidden" o objeto era escondido no proprio form de construção de design, neste momento mesmo que defina a propriedade para "Hidden" o objecto continua visivel.

Explicando melhor:

Na imagem abaixo como a propriedade Visibility da Grid A está defefina para Hidden, nem a gridA nem o labelA deveriam estar visíveis. No antigo PC funciona perfeitamente mas não me recordo onde configuro isto no VS2010

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem sabe onde posso configurar isto no VS2010?

Comment: Tentasse reiniciar as configurações do VS para as de fábrica?

Comment: Tente postar seu código xaml, pode ser algo nele

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou usar o `Visibility.Collapsed`?

O Hidden não irá mostrar o elemento, mas irá reservar o espaço para ele.

O texto exato conforme o [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx):

`Visible`: Mostra o elemento.

`Hidden`: Não mostra o elemento, porém reserva o seu espaço no layout.

`Collapsed`: Não mostra o elemento e não reserva o seu espaço no layout.

Comment: Olá. Obrigado pela resposta. Sim já experimentei essa propriedade também, mas não é por ai. o hidden ou collapsed apenas fazem com que os objetos fiquem invisiveis quando o projecto é executado.. o Meu problema não é esse, mas sim antes de compilar o projeto, é na construção do design..

Comment: Hmm, certo.Tentasse reiniciar as configurações do VS para as de fábrica?